# Format date with vanilla javascript without using a package

Tags: javascript

I have some dates fetched from an API that are formatted like this `1960-06-21`.

I want to write a function that formats the date to this instead `21 June 1960`.

There's lot's of people online suggesting to just use a library such as moment.js but I would like to try with just JavaScript using the most modern features if possible.

Is this even possible?

I found this explanation of converting a single date

```js
const d = new Date('1993-10-30');
  const dtf = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: '2-digit',
  });
  const [{ value: mo }, , { value: da }, , { value: ye }] = dtf.formatToParts(
    d
  );

  console.log(`${da} ${mo} ${ye}`);
// 30 October 1993
```

But this example only takes one date and I have 100s of dates coming from an API so need it to be a flexible function.

Comment: Is there an issue with making a function out of this, using that `d` as your input parameter?

Comment: I'd love to be able to think myself of how I would do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fairly simple to just use the input strings, if they are always well-formed ISO 8601 dates:

```js
const monthNames = [
  'January', 'February', 'March',     'April',   'May',      'June',
  'July',    'August',   'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'
]

const reformatDate = (iso) => {
  const [year, month, day] = iso.split('-')
  return `${Number(day)} ${monthNames[Number(month) - 1]} ${year}`
}

console .log (
  reformatDate ('1960-06-21')  //~> "21 June 1960"
)

// Or to do a list of dates:
const dates = ['1865-04-15', '1881-07-02', '1901-09-19', '1963-11-22']
console .log (
  dates .map (reformatDate)
  //~> ["15 April 1865", "2 July 1881", "19 September 1901", "22 November 1963"]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the methods supported my Date:

```js
function df(date){
  const m = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
  return date.getUTCDate()+' '+m[date.getUTCMonth()]+' '+date.getUTCFullYear();
}
const dt = new Date('1960-06-21');
console.log(df(dt));
```

Answer (score 1):

Any reason why you can't create a function and reuse it?

Example:

```js
const dtf = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  day: '2-digit',
  timeZone: 'UTC'
});

function formatDate(date, format) {
  const [{ value: mo }, , { value: da }, , { value: ye }] = format.formatToParts(date);

  return `${da} ${mo} ${ye}`;
}

const dates = ['1993-10-30', '2003-10-29', '1999-12-30'];

console.log(dates
  .map(date => Date.parse(date))
  .map(date => formatDate(date, dtf))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
const dt = new Date('1960-06-21');

const convert = (date) =>{
    const dateArr = date.toString().split(' ')
    return dateArr[2] +' '+dateArr[1] +' '+dateArr[3]
}

console.log(convert(dt))
```